# Searching for Specifc String in Array in LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, split

example of string array stored in DB = "SA|IL|RC|AL|IN" per residence

User can search on specific option

```
allResidence = allResidence.Where(x => x.LivingOptions.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Contains(searchCriteria.LivingOptionCode));
```

this causes an issue if user searches on I - i want it to return 0 but using **Contains** will obviously return IL & IN as valid options

so how to split and check for specific entry

tried using **Equals**

```
allResidence = allResidence.Where(x => x.LivingOptions.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Equals(searchCriteria.LivingOptionCode));
```

but that returns 0 when searching for IL example

Comment: Can't you normalize your database design instead?

Comment: Try this `allResidence = allResidence.Where(x => x.LivingOptions.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Any(x => x == searchCriteria.LivingOptionCode))`

Comment: @Dai in this instance no database design cant be altered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer provided by @DemetriusAxenowski

```
allResidence = allResidence.Where(x => x.LivingOptions.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Any(x => x == searchCriteria.LivingOptionCode))
```